# Xna studio 4. Pixel drawing

Tags: c#, xna

1 ) Hey. I need help with pixels... How can i draw pixels with less lagg in draw function? While i am drawing them then my processor usage is 40%, it's too much for that.

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
                spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
                spriteBatch.Draw(grasspixel, screenpos, Color.Red);
                GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
                DrawGround(spriteBatch, 1024, 768, screenpos, grasspixel);
                spriteBatch.End();

                base.Draw(gameTime);            
        }
```

Here is DrawGround function:

```
public void DrawGround(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, int screen_X, int screen_Y, Vector2 screenPosition, Texture2D texture)
        {
            Vector2 tempVector = Vector2.Zero;
            for (int i = 1; i <= screen_X; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= screen_Y; j++)
                {
                    if (earth[i, j] == 1)
                    {
                        tempVector.X = i;
                        tempVector.Y = j;
                        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, tempVector, Color.Blue);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

In DrawGround I get pixel locations from an array and then return them to Vector2.

2 ) Do I need to draw my map every frame?

Is there a special buffer or something like that to do this?
Sorry if I ask something stupid, but I'm new to XNA.
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are drawing **786432** (1024*768) sprites per frame. Each sprite consists of 2 triangles, that need to be streched and positioned, not to forget all the texture sampling. SpriteBatch is fast, but not that fast.

Normally you would draw your grass texture over a larger area, using a sprite that is more than 1*1 pixels in size. Drawing one sprite for every pixel on screen really defeats the whole purpose of it.

So combine your grass pixels in an image editing program to a texture and use a few large sprites to draw your ground. That should bring your FPS to a reasonable rate.

---

If you *really* need to write data to a texture on a per pixel basis, use the [`Texture2D.SetData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.texture2d.setdata.aspx) method.

Comment: I am currently drawing .bmp which size is 1x1 px.

Comment: I am currently drawing .bmp which size is 1x1 px.
Is there some way to draw those pixels without .bmp. Just draw pixels. Wouldn't that be faster?
And.. Is there other way to draw(without spritebach) and wouldn't that be faster,less laggy.
Thanks.

Comment: Edited my answer. Nevertheless, Direct3D graphics are vector based. Always consider the per pixel solution as a last resort.

Comment: there is no single pixel drawing in xna, only by texture. create seamless grass tiles 32x32 or larger. or 1024x768 big grass image, and then put over that other tiles that are not so often drawn (roads, buildings).